# TinyMCE Copy/Paste Access to Clipboard

Tags: tinymce, clipboard, copy-paste

If I attempt a copy/paste into the TinyMCE editor I receive the message "Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard.  Please use the CTRL+X/C/V shortcuts instead"..... however I can copy/paste into the code view ?

I can even try this on your web site demo with the same results, regardless of what browser is being used.  Also same results on Mac OS or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior in TinyMCE.

Modern browsers don't support the use of JavaScript (triggered by a button or menu) to access the clipboard.  This is a security measure browser vendors put in place a while back, to prevent nefarious actors from implementing JavaScript on a page that could take clipboard contents without the end user's knowledge or consent.  The supported way to perform a copy/paste is via keyboard commands for copy, cut, and paste.

Tiny is the aware of things like the [Asynchronous Clipboard API](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/async-clipboard/), however at this point that API lacks the width or depth of features needed to make it useful for processing HTML and image data.  The TinyMCE engineering team have been monitoring this API to find ways we can improve the consistency of the paste process in TinyMCE.  Once this API can handle HTML with consistent support across browsers, we will consider introducing this into TinyMCE.

Comment: Why then can a copy/paste be conducted into the code view window ?

Comment: It seems that TinyMCE hasn't actually *implemented* the async clipboard API even though they wrote a lengthy blog article about it in 2021: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/7254